# Найти сумму ряда с точностью до члена ряда

Tags: c++builder, c++

Помогите пожалуйста с задачей ,
вот условие 
Найти сумму ряда с точностью до члена ряда, меньшего 0.0001 для заданного значения и сравнить эту сумму с функцией контроля. Для вычисления последующего значения члена ряда использовать рекуррентную формулу.
http://stuffed.ru/images/100197-latex.html
значение х :-1<x<1
Функция контроля:arctg x

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
double x,stx,sint,e;
    int i,fakt,z;
    cout << "vvedi x " << endl;
    cin>>x;
    cout << "vvedi e " << endl;
    cin>>e;

 stx= x;  
 fakt= 1;  
 sint= 0;  
 i= 1;  
 z= 1;
    while (stx/fakt>=e)
 {
                      sint=sint+z*stx/fakt;
                      i=i+2;
                      stx=stx*x*x;
                      fakt=fakt*(i-1)*i;
                      z=z*(-1);
 }
 double g =  sin((double)(x));
 cout <<"SIN: "<< g << endl;
 cout <<"SINT"<< sint << endl;
 if ( g==sint)
 {cout<<"ravni";}
 else
 {cout<<"ne ravni";}
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: А в чем трудность возникает? Или просто необходимо решить задачу за вас?

Comment: @f1292298, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: После установки dev c++ 5.4.2,при запуске программ возникает ошибка
[Error] iostream.h: No such file or directory
хотя до этого все работало ,и я немогу толком проверить свою программу ,если вам нетрудно можете мне дать уже готовою

Comment: дать вам готовую?)) Шутите что ли?  Это за деньги и не на этом сайте

Comment: >>[Error] iostream.h: No such file or directory

Ну значит что-то не так поставили/настроили, а значит и готовая прога не пойдет)

Comment: @f1292298, Вы знаете, самое смешное, что в винде в MinGW g++ 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3) программа оттранслировалась без ошибок.

Тогда в чем вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

> [Error] iostream.h: No such file or directory

что следует из сообщения об ошибке, вам нужно подключить iostream.h. В чем проблема-то?

Comment: я пробовал скинуть папку include с либами от предыдущий версии но не помогло

Comment: @f1292298, а вы пробовали в первой строчке вместо #include <iostream> написать #include <iostream.h>?

Comment: @Макс Жуков а вы сами-то уверены в правильности того, что советуете? iostream уже давным-давно (если не ошибаюсь, со стандарта 1998 года) в директиве #include пишется без .h. И все эти <iostream.h> - э то чушь.И вышеописанная проблема имеет несколько  иные корни

Comment: Что-то не то. Если компилятор не находит именно `iostream.h`, значит, у ТС `#include <iostreаm.h>`, и он дал нам не тот код. Или где-то подменил системный header на более старую версию. Короче, пусть настроит среду, в которой скомпилируется hello world, а потом всё остальное.

Comment: Старая песня о iostream.h ? Перешёл с древнего борландкомпайлера на что-то более современное...

Comment: @DreamChild, исходя из сообщения об ошибке это первый логичный вариант

Comment: Парни ВОУ ВОУ ПАРЕНЬ ПОЛЕГЧЕ
Придется на паре все запускать и проверять

Comment: Кто может помочь исправить ее и за сколько ?

Comment: @f1292298, переходите на линукс. Подобные проблемы исчезнут.

Comment: @avp в учебной лаборатории свои порядки...